# Controller for an Administrator User, can this be improved? (codeigniter)

Tags: php, performance, object-oriented, mvc, codeigniter

I want to write better code.
This is a simple controller class for an administrator login.

Are there conventions or tips in PHP to rewrite this code and improve it?

```
<?php

class Administrators extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('/office/administrators/login');
        } else {
            redirect('/office/dashboard/');
        } 
    }

    public function login() {

        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('/office/dashboard/');
        } 

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

             $a = new Administrator();

            if($a->login($this->input->post('email'),$this->input->post('password'))) {
                    redirect('/office/dashboard/');
            } else {
                $this->messages->add('Unable to authenticate you', 'error');

            }
        }

        $data['error_messages'] = $this->messages->get('error'); 
        $this->load->view('/office/administrators/login', $data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->simpleloginsecure->logout();
        redirect('office/administrators/login');
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Joseph's post. I agree with it mostly, but the first comment I'd like to clarify. A PHP opening tag should definitely be the first item on the page to avoid headers being sent prematurely, but the opening tag `<?php` or `<?` does not make a difference and depends upon your server. The traditional, long, PHP opener is usually the accepted norm because not all servers accept the later and it can cause compatibility issues. Such as if you were to include XML in your PHP then doing `<?xml` might cause issues. However, most all servers have a setting that allows you to enable it "[short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)". People still use the shorter form, but it does not have any performance differences. I'm sure this is what he meant, but originally reading it I thought he was saying that switching to the short form did that. So there's clarification.

Only other thing I want to point out is the following comment: "you can use the input class's post() to check for the post request". I'm not sure about CI, but unless it does the same `REQUEST_METHOD` check in its interior, then what you have there currently is fine. I just had a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999293/is-serverrequest-method-still-viable) on SO about checking the `$_POST` vs checking the `REQUEST_METHOD` and it is much better to check the request method. Checking the post array will work, but only because it is a hack. From the looks of this CI statement it is a similar thing. But I'd suggest looking into it for clarification.

**Now, here are my suggestions:**

Don't override a parent method if you aren't going to extend it. The child class inherits it automagically. The only reason to call the constructor again, or any inherited method for that matter, is if you were going to change something, extend it, before or after the parent method. Example, say you wanted to change a property `$newProperty` before it was used in the parent constructor (constructor is a bad example think a normal method). Then you can set that property just before calling it so that the parent method can use that new value. Or say that your parent method has a local variable `$newVar` and you want to use it in your new class. Then you can save that variable as a property or do something with it immediately in local scope. In short, just delete your constructor it is unnecessary as is.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->newProperty = 'jkl';//can be used in parent method
    parent::__construct();
    echo $newVar;//came from parent method
    $this->newVar = $newVar;
}
```

Give your program some defaults instead of using if/else statements and/or calling methods multiple times. Doing this makes it easier to change functionality should you desire it. Say you didn't want to use redirect anymore, but maybe view instead, you'd have to change each occurrence of it. There's only two here, but if you had more it could be a pain.

```
public function index() {
    $redirect = '/office/dashboard/';

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        $redirect = '/office/administrators/login';
    }

    redirect( $redirect );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- the very first characters should be `<?` to avoid whitespace from being sent in the response. This saves you from issues with header redirects. You should also omit the closing `?>` for the same reason (whitespaces).

  > [In order for this function to work it must be used before anything is outputted to the browser since it utilizes server headers.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)
- you can use the input class's post() to check for the post request.

  > [The function (`post()`) returns FALSE (boolean) if there are no items in the POST.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Here's modified code with comments:

```
<?php
//should be the very first characters

class Administrators extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //factor out the login check to isolate the common logic
    //also, for understandability, boolean checks should be prefixed
    //with "is" or "has" like phrases 
    //like "is it like this?", "[something] has this?"
    private function isLoggedIn(){
       return $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    }

    public function index() {

        //use our new "isLoggedIn()"
        if(isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect('/office/dashboard/');
        } else {
            redirect('/office/administrators/login');
        } 
    }

    public function login() {

        if(isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect('/office/dashboard/');
        } 

        //you can use the input class's post() to check for the post request
        if($this->input->post()) {

            //for readability, it's more appropriate to
            //assign these values to verbose variables names...
            $administrator = new Administrator();
            $username = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            //...so we know what arguments were sent
            if($administrator->login($username,$password)) {
                redirect('/office/dashboard/');
            } else {
                $this->messages->add('Unable to authenticate you', 'error');
            }
        }

        $data['error_messages'] = $this->messages->get('error'); 
        $this->load->view('/office/administrators/login', $data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->simpleloginsecure->logout();
        redirect('office/administrators/login');
    }

}

//remove the closing ?>.
```